# Magento Full Text Search through API

Tags: magento-1.9, api, catalogsearch, fulltext

I have an API2 REST end point that is trying to do a full text search. The problem is that it's always returning empty results for not specific reason. This is the code i have:

```
        $query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')
                    ->setQueryText($keyword)
                    ->prepare();

        $fulltextResource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext')->prepareResult(
            Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/fulltext'), 
            $keyword, 
            $query
        );

        $collection->getSelect()->joinInner(
                    array('search_result' => $collection->getTable('catalogsearch/result')),
                    $collection->getConnection()->quoteInto(
                        'search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id=?',
                        $query->getId()
                    ),
                    array('relevance' => 'relevance')
                );
        $products = $collection->load();
```

I tried debugging the sql queries (by turning on the PDO debug flag) and got the following:

```
## 2017-12-23 11:43:32
## 24156 ## QUERY
SQL: SELECT `s`.`product_id`, SUM(rel) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT `s`.`product_id`, (( 1 + MATCH (s.data_index1) AGAINST (:query) ) * 5.0625) AS `rel` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s` WHERE (s.store_id = 2) AND ((`s`.`data_index1` LIKE '%granero%')) UNION SELECT `s`.`product_id`, (( 1 + MATCH (s.data_index2) AGAINST (:query) ) * 3.375) AS `rel` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s` WHERE (s.store_id = 2) AND (MATCH (s.data_index2) AGAINST (:queryinwhere IN BOOLEAN MODE)) UNION SELECT `s`.`product_id`, (( 1 + MATCH (s.data_index3) AGAINST (:query) ) * 2.25) AS `rel` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s` WHERE (s.store_id = 2) AND (MATCH (s.data_index3) AGAINST (:queryinwhere IN BOOLEAN MODE)) UNION SELECT `s`.`product_id`, (( 1 + MATCH (s.data_index4) AGAINST (:query) ) * 1.5) AS `rel` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s` WHERE (s.store_id = 2) AND (MATCH (s.data_index4) AGAINST (:queryinwhere IN BOOLEAN MODE)) UNION SELECT `s`.`product_id`, (( 1 + MATCH (s.data_index5) AGAINST (:query) ) * 1) AS `rel` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s` WHERE (s.store_id = 2) AND (MATCH (s.data_index5) AGAINST (:queryinwhere IN BOOLEAN MODE))) AS `s`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = s.product_id GROUP BY `product_id`
BIND: array (
  ':queryinwhere' => 'granero*',
  ':query' => 'granero',
)
AFF: 544
TIME: 0.3334
```

Which returns the right results when being executed directly on the database using PhpAdmin or SQL WorkBench.

I tried printing the $collection->getSelect()->__toString() and got the following:

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`administracion`, `e`.`alertas`, `e`.`composicion`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`destacado`, `e`.`formato`, `e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`indicacion`, `e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`manufacturer`, `e`.`manufacturer_value`, `e`.`modo_uso`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`precauciones`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`principio_activo`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`sello`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`status`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`weight`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min
```

Which is weird, since I though I would get the same query I debugged from the PDO adapter.

And for the tables in the database:

- catalogsearch_fulltext: Table looks solid, everything is indexed the right way
- catalogsearch_query: The query i searched for are all there
- catalogsearch_result: This one is always empty, not sure whether it's normal

Any clue on what I might be doing wrong?